# how to select and sort the one row by each customer

Tags: php, sql

i have one table of properties. i want to select all the properties.

but i want to arrange those properties like 1 property of customer A, 1 property of customer B, 1 property of customer C and so on like the following.

```
customer    Property ID
 A              1001
 B              900
 C              1002
 D              1003
 A              799
 B              803
 C              600
 D              670
```

how can i do this ? any help appreciated.

Regards

Comment: are you looking for a mysql way or php+mysql?

Comment: post your table schema

Comment: can you provide an example of the result expected?

Comment: he had put the result expected please read the question.

Comment: Which DB server do you use?

Comment: does each customer have all the properties? Will it always be A,B,C,D, A,B,C,D... or will it end up being stuff like A,B,D, A,D, A?

Comment: @MoVod for a good programmer does not make any sence.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT customer, property_id FROM mytable");

$output = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $output[$row['customer']][] = $row['property_id'];
}

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Seems clear to me. He want to group the data by customers and he is willing to use PHP and MySQL

Comment: i wanted to show first property by each customer, then 2nd property by each and so on. i think only group by does not work.

Comment: but not complete he wants to have the mentioned table a little code is needed to create the table as expected

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer pure **SQL** solution (working on MySQL):

```
SET @rank = 1;
SET @prev = '';

SELECT customer, property
FROM (SELECT *,
      IF(@prev <> customer, @rank := 1, @rank := @rank + 1) AS rank,
      IF(@prev <> customer, @prev := customer, NULL)
      FROM properties
      ORDER BY customer) AS ranked
ORDER BY rank, customer;
```

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6790bf/1).

The idea is to enumerate all properties with consecutive numbers **1..n** inside each customer and then take properties with `rank = 1` at first, followed by those with `rank = 2`, and so on ...